# Appfuse user management from administrator end - setting password vs password hint

Tags: appfuse

On appfuse (http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Demos), an Administrator can add users. When adding a new user, the administrator can set "Password Hint" for the user being added, but not the user's actual password. When the user comes to login, how will the user know his exact password, my question is?

Comment: Which web framework are you using? Spring MVC and Struts 2 will email the user an activation link that they can use to set their password.

Comment: Ok thanks. Noticed an unrelated potential improvement. When I use the emailed link to update the newly added user's password - and I am logged in as another user - the message I get after updating the password is "Your password .. been updated". The "Your" is incorrect - isn't it - should be The <name of user>'s password has been updated?

Comment: Noticed one more - an email with (No Subject) from appfuse. Please see here - no way to attach screen shot: (No Subject)‏


(No Subject)
AppFuse (appXYZ....@raiblXYZigns.com)  Add to contacts  5:56 AM   Keep this message at the top of your inbox  
To: first last
appXYZ....@raiblXYZigns.com
Parts of this message have been blocked for your safety.
Show content|I trust appXYZ....@raiblXYZigns.com. Always show content.
Your password has been updated

Login at: http://demo.appfuse.org/appfuse-spring

Comment: Please add these as issues to http://issues.appfuse.org and we'll get them fixed. Make sure and include the steps to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

When administrator add some user, they only filled the the password hint. 
And the password will be sent to user's email that has been registered.

Comment: The first answer, which says "will email the user an activation link that they can use to set their password", is more accurate